# MATLAB random numbers below a threshold

Tags: matlab, random, normal-distribution

I use `normrnd` and `lognormrnd` to sample numbers according to these two distribution functions. Nevertheless, since I am using quite large standard deviations, I sample several numbers that are above a threshold I put for my code. My question is: is there a way to sample numbers according to this distributions but within a certain threshold without using an if_bigger --> sample_again function?

Comment: You will need to implement such a function yourself. Note that once you do this, you can't really say that the random numbers come from the distribution you initially generate them from, though whether this matters in practice is a matter of circumstances.

Comment: perhaps a better question on [stats.se]